# python: passing a variable to mapped function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am mapping one array to another using a function called `filter_json` as such:

```
filtered_json = map(filter_json, data_json)

def filter_json(data_json):
    """Filter data_json to data that is needed"""
    ...
    # return mapped dictionary
```

Now I want to the `filter_json` function to accept another parameter. Something like this (but this obviously doesn't work):

```
filtered_json = map(filter_json, data_json, var)

def filter_json(data_json, var):
    """Filter data_json to data that is needed"""
    ... # do something with var
    # return mapped dictionary
```

How do I pass in more variables into `filter_json`?

Comment: Two approaches:   (1) look into `functools.partial`;   (2) consider using a list comprehension instead of `map`

Comment: If you could please include some code

Answer (score 3):

Two potential approaches:

1. use `functools.partial`

   ```
   import functools
   f = functools.partial(filter_json, var=var)
   filtered_json = map(f, data_json)
   ```
2. ... or use a list comprehension instead of `map`:

   ```
   filtered_json = [ filter_json(x, var) for x in data_json ]
   ```

   If you want an lazily-evaluated iterator rather than a `list`,  use round brackets instead of square brackets—then it's called a generator expression rather than a list comprehension.

I generally prefer option 2, on grounds of readability, and the flexibility to include `if` conditionals and nested loops in the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda to call the function with the variable you want

```
filtered_json = map(lambda data: filter_json(data, var), data_json)

def filter_json(data_json, var):
    """Filter data_json to data that is needed"""
    ... # do something with var
    # return mapped dictionary
```